# Download and Install a .exe File using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I wanna create an auto-updater for my project which downloads and installs a file from the internet. I have done how I can download the file to my desired location with a desired name. The place where I am stuck is how I can install the file.

The code so far I have written:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import getpass

url = 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/artigence/files/latest/download'

print('File Downloading')

usrname = getpass.getuser()
destination = f'C:\\Users\\{usrname}\\Downloads\\download.exe'

download = urlretrieve(url, destination)

print('File downloaded')
```

And the file is downloaded to my downloads folder. Now, how can I install the .exe file using python?

Comment: You can use [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to control an application. Take a look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the `subprocess` module to execute the `.exe` files.

```
import subprocess

cmd = "{download location} batch.exe"

returned_value = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)  # returns the exit code in unix
print('returned value:', returned_value)
```

[refer](https://www.journaldev.com/16140/python-system-command-os-subprocess-call#python-subprocesscall-function)

I strongly suggest not to use `pyautogui` for this.

Comment: "installing the .exe"... how to install an application using `os`?

Comment: `.exe` is essentially a command on it's own, so calling it via a shell script or a bat file should be enough, or, in this case, make a single line command to invoke the file

Comment: If it is an `installer.exe` then won't we require to select options while installing like `install location` and the numerous `next` buttons? How to do that with `os`?

Comment: You could check online for the installer, and hope to find some arguments that will allow you to skip it, but if it's an installation wizard, you will have no choice other that `pyautogui`. This can get messy with `pyautogui` though, as it relies on the (x,y) co-ordinates of the screen, so you may face a lot of unrequired compatibility issues.

Comment: Yep that is the reason I recommended `pyautogui` it will work in all cases :-). Messy yes, but still reliable :)

Comment: Samridh Tuladhar thnx a ton. this worked and i am not thinking of using pyautogui for now, right now I am going for PySide2. But again, thnx a tonn!

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar correct your answer; you haven't used the ```os``` module yourself